# No activity in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I just installed Android Studio and tried to code something but there is no activity i just have these files in my explorer. Any ideas why?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTAVd.png

Comment: Create your own activity

Comment: I did so, on the start, when i was configuring the name, icons etc. But i can't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Right click on the 'src/main' folder, select 'New' and then 'Directory', name it 'java'. (It will turn blue btw).
- Right click the new 'java' directory you created and select 'New' and select 'Package', enter your package name. (com.your.package.name)
- Right click the package that was created for you, select 'New', then 'Android Component', enter a name for it, make sure 'Activity' is selected as 'Kind', and enter a label.

If you are having too many issues though, might as well just create a new project from scratch :)

Comment: There is no Package option. I think there is something wrong with my studio, there is no toolbox or whatever is called like it was on the SDK. P.S - I reinstalled the studio and it's the same.

Comment: Did you specify an Android SDK location?

Comment: Well no.There wasn't a field for specify. I deleted the old SDK with Eclipse and installed the studio because android website is says studio have sdk.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this issue occurs if there's a special character in the path of the project.
[Issue on google code](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56397)